# need help in inner join query

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.*, table3.*
FROM table1, table2, table3
inner join 
 (
   select table1.id AS pid, max(table1.createtime) AS timestamp
   from table1 group by table1.id
 ) A on A.pid = table1.id AND A.timestamp = table1.createtime
WHERE table3.id = table1.id
ORDER BY table1.createtime;
```

I am trying to fetch only the last modified record for each id in table1.

For the above query I am getting error as:

```
"%s:invalid identifier" for  "A.timestamp = table1.IDA2A2" this part.
```

Please let me know what is wrong with this query.
 DB is Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well part of your problem is you are mixing `JOIN` syntax - your query is using both comma joins and ANSI JOIN syntax.  You need to properly join the tables:

```
SELECT t1.,t2., t3.* 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3
  on t1.id = t3.id
inner join 
(
  select table1.id AS pid, max(table1.createtime) AS timestamp 
  from table1 
  group by table1.id
) A 
  on A.pid = t1.id 
  AND A.timestamp = t1.createtime 
ORDER BY t1.createtime;
```